# Can we extend this proposition to complex-valued functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, markov-chains, expected-value

I'm reading

**Markov Chains and Mixing Times** by *David A. Levin*, *Yuval Peres*, *Elizabeth L. Wilmer*, *James G. Propp*, *David B. Wilson*

and I'm trying to figure out if this Proposition can be applied when $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$.

First recall that
if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two probability distributions defined on a state space $\Omega$. The total variation distance between these two probability distributions is defined as
\begin{equation*}
    d_{TV}(\mu,\nu)=||\mu-\nu||_{TV}:= \max_{A \subseteq \Omega} |\mu(A) - \nu(A)|
\end{equation*}
where $\mu(A) = \sum_{ x \in A}\mu(x) $.
Also recall that given a probability distribution $\mu$ defined on $\Omega$ and $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, denote by $E_\mu[X] = \int_{\Omega}X(\omega) \ \mu(d\omega)$ the expectation of $X$ with respect $\mu$. Likewise, $Var_\mu(X)$ denotes the variance of $X$ with respect to $\mu$.

**Proposition.**
Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two probability distributions on a finite state space $\Omega$ and let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real valued function on $\Omega$. Then,
\begin{equation}\label{PeresBound}
    ||\mu- \nu||_{TV} \geq 1 - 8 \  \frac{\max\{Var_\mu(f),Var_\nu(f)\}}{|E_\mu[f]-E_\nu[f]|^2}.
\end{equation}

*Proof.*
Assume without loss of generality that $E_\mu[f] \geq E_\nu[f]$ and let $$r:=\frac{|E_\mu[f]-E_\nu[f]|}{\sigma_*}=\frac{|E_\mu[f]-E_\nu[f]|}{\sqrt{\max\{Var_\mu(f),Var_\nu(f)\}}}.$$ If $I := (E_\nu[f] + \frac{r}{2} \sigma_*, \infty) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, by Chebyshev's inequality,
\begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            \nu f^{-1}(I) & = \nu( f- E_\nu[f] >  \tfrac{r}{2} \sigma_*) \leq \nu( |f-E_\nu[f]| > \tfrac{r}{2} Var_\nu[f]) \leq \frac{4}{r^2}\\
            \mu f^{-1}(I) & = \mu( f > E_\mu[f] - |E_\nu[f] - E_\mu[f]| + \tfrac{r}{2} \sigma_*) = \mu( E_\mu[f] - f < \tfrac{r}{2} Var_\mu[f]) \geq 1 - \frac{4}{r^2}.
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
        ||\mu f^{-1} - \nu f^{-1}||_{TV} \geq | \mu f^{-1}(I) - \nu f^{-1}(I)| \geq 1 - \frac{8}{r^2}
    \end{equation*}
and by **Lemma**, since $f: \Omega \to f(\Omega)$ with $f(\Omega)$ finite,
\begin{equation*}
        ||\mu  - \nu||_{TV} = ||\mu f^{-1} - \nu f^{-1}||_{TV} \geq 1 - \frac{8}{r^2} =1- 8 \  \frac{\max\{Var_\mu(f),Var_\nu(f)\}}{|E_\mu[f]-E_\nu[f]|^2}.
    \end{equation*}

**Lemma.**
Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be probability distributions on $\Omega$ and let $f: \Omega \to \Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a finite set. Then
\begin{equation*}
   ||\mu-\nu||_{TV} \geq ||\mu f^{-1} -\nu f^{-1}||_{TV},
\end{equation*}
where \begin{equation*}
\mu f^{-1} (I) := \mu( f^{-1}(I)) = \mu( f \in I).
\end{equation*}

*Proof.*
For $J \subseteq \Gamma$, since $$| \mu f^{-1} (J) - \nu f^{-1} (J) | = | \mu (f^{-1} (J)) - \nu (f^{-1} (J)) |,$$ it follows that
$$||\mu-\nu||_{TV} = \max_{ I \subseteq \Omega}| \mu (I) - \nu (I) | \geq \max_{J \subseteq \Gamma} | \mu f^{-1} (J) - \nu f^{-1} (J) | = ||\mu f^{-1} -\nu f^{-1}||_{TV}.$$

> My question is if I can use **Proposition** when $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$. It would be very usefull for me to estimate the total variation distance using a complex-valued random variable. However, I look at the proof of the **Proposition** and it seems that it wouldn't be true when $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$... Is there an equivalent result of this proposition for complex-valued functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we just have to change it to

\begin{equation}
    ||\mu- \nu||_{TV} \geq 1 - 8 \  \frac{\max\{Var_\mu(f),Var_\nu(f)\}}{|\ |E_\mu[f]|-|E_\nu[f]|\ |^2}.
\end{equation}

The proof is then similar and uses the fact that for two complex numbers $w, z,$
$$|z|-|w| \leq |\ |z|-|w|\ | \leq |z-w|.$$

Assume without loss of generality that $|E_\mu[f]| \geq |E_\nu[f]|$ and let $$r:=\frac{|\ |E_\mu[f]|-|E_\nu[f]|\ |}{\sigma_*}=\frac{|\ |E_\mu[f]|-|E_\nu[f]| \ |}{\sqrt{\max\{Var_\mu(f),Var_\nu(f)\}}}.$$ If $I := (|E_\nu[f]| + \frac{r}{2} \sigma_*, \infty) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $g:= |f|$, by Chebyshev's inequality,

\begin{equation*}
            \begin{split}
                \nu g^{-1}(I) & = \nu( |f|- |E_\nu[f]| >  \tfrac{r}{2} \sigma_*) \leq \nu( | f|-|E_\nu[f] | > \tfrac{r}{2} Var_\nu[f]) \\
& \leq \nu( |f-E_\nu[f]| > \tfrac{r}{2} Var_\nu[f])  \leq \frac{4}{r^2}\\
                \mu g^{-1}(I) & = \mu( |f| > |E_\mu[f]| - |\ |E_\nu[f]| - |E_\mu[f]|\ | + \tfrac{r}{2} \sigma_*) = \mu( |E_\mu[f]| - |f| < \tfrac{r}{2} \sigma_*)\\
                & \geq  \mu( |E_\mu[f]| - |f| < \tfrac{r}{2} Var_\mu[f]) 
                \geq \mu( |E_\mu[f] - f| < \tfrac{r}{2} Var_\mu[f]) \geq 1 - \frac{4}{r^2}.
            \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
            ||\mu g^{-1} - \nu g^{-1}||_{TV} \geq | \mu g^{-1}(I) - \nu g^{-1}(I)| \geq 1 - \frac{8}{r^2}
\end{equation*}
and by **Lemma**, since $g: \Omega \to |f(\Omega)|$ with $f(\Omega)$ finite,
\begin{equation*}
        ||\mu  - \nu ||_{TV} \geq ||\mu g^{-1} - \nu g^{-1}||_{TV} \geq 1 - \frac{8}{r^2} =1- 8 \  \frac{\max\{Var_\mu(f),Var_\nu(f)\}}{|\ |E_\mu[f]|-|E_\nu[f]|\ |^2}.
\end{equation*}